# Register App in spring cloud data flow from docker hub when there is no internet

Tags: docker-registry, spring-cloud-dataflow

How to get application Properties on registering app in spring cloud data flow from docker hub when there is no internet

Answer (score 0):

For air-gapped environments, you may want to pull the images on the connected machine and then relocate them to the air-gapped boxes that have a private registry in them. There are a few tools out there that can help you with the relocation.

For SCDF on K8s, we ship the [relocation tool](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf-k8s/1-2/relocating-ootb-apps.html) to help with it, as well.